# HikariCP and JdbcTemplate (autocommit=false)

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate, hikaricp

I have set up my hikariCP datasource to `autoCommit = false`, `maximumConnection` of 1. I've used this dataSource in my `JdbcTemplate`, and upon calling `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().commit()`, my data was not flushed.
Why commit does not work with hikariCP datasource?

I've tried to changed my `dataSource` to `SingleConnectionDataSource` and it works fine.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: @user7294900 I am just wondering why calling commit() does not work with HikariCP datasource?

Comment: Because `getConnection` gets a new connection each time. You shouldn't be committing data yourself. Either let Spring do it with transactions or use `JdbcTemplate` with `ConnectionCallback` if you really must/want to do that.

Comment: It's a pool of connections. The fact that you limit it to 1 doesn't mean that you'll get always the same connection. Get the connection, store it in a variable, use it, commit, then close it to give it back to the pool.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it will only return the same connection since i limit the number of connections to 1.

Comment: No, also realise that the code shown will leak connections, because you need to call `close()` on the connection to return the connection back to the connection pool.